# Simulate right key event every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

Im trying to simulate a keyboard press that happens every five seconds. I have the following code but it is giving me an error. Can anyone help me see whats going wrong here?

```
window.setInterval(function(){
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.keyCode = 39;
jQuery('body').trigger(e);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: can you just use $('body').trigger(e); instead of jQuery('body').trigger(e);

Comment: Yes, please show us the error. I've made this fiddle with your code and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/83Pbr/ . Please post your HTML and all the included scripts, maybe jQuery gets broken in your particular page.

Answer (score -2):

use

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {callYourFunction();}, 5000);
```